# Xamarin Listview only adding 1 item my List has 2 items on it

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

I have a listview and a method to get the items via Bluethoot conection to a Radio device, when the method ends i have two items in my itemsList but only one is showing on my ListView, also the item is not visible until i click the screen for some reason.

Any help on how to present my two items at once inside of the ListView?

I think it has something to do with the way im handling the EventRead and EventStopped, maybe its not getting any time to update

```
public partial class ReadAnyPage : ContentPage
    {
        IRadioPlatform _platform;
        DropdownTypes dropdownTypes;

        Task<List<ChoiceConnectEndpoint>> _readAnyComplete;
        public event EventHandler OnStopped;
        public event EventHandler<Itron.Mobile.Radio.Communication.SRead.HandledEventArgs<ChoiceConnectEndpoint>> readEndpoints;
        private List<JsonDict> itemsList = new List<JsonDict>();
        string bleName, blePort;

        public ReadAnyPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this; //Added this

            _platform = DependencyService.Get<IRadioPlatform>();

            dropdownTypes = new DropdownTypes();

            bleName = Preferences.Get("ble_name", "");
            blePort = Preferences.Get("ble_port", "");

            CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

            listView.ItemsSource = itemsList;

            ReadAnyNear(tokenSource, token);
        }

        private void ReadAnyNear(CancellationTokenSource tokenSource, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var loading = UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Reading Endpoints...", onCancel: tokenSource.Cancel, "\n\n" + Resx.Resources.Cancel, true, MaskType.Black);

            try
            {
                // Set new IMR
                IMRRadioService imrRadioService = new IMRRadioService(_platform);

                imrRadioService.Name = bleName;
                imrRadioService.Port = blePort;string

                readEndpoints += EventRead;
                OnStopped += EventStopped;

                _readAnyComplete = imrRadioService.ReadAny(token, readEndpoints, OnStopped);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Error", dropdownTypes.OnConvertErrorEX(ex.Message), "ok", "cancel");

            }

            loading.Hide();
        }

        private void EventRead(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("READ READ");

            try
            {
                Itron.Mobile.Radio.Communication.SRead.HandledEventArgs<ChoiceConnectEndpoint> item = (Itron.Mobile.Radio.Communication.SRead.HandledEventArgs<ChoiceConnectEndpoint>)e;

                JsonDict jsonDict = new JsonDict();

                jsonDict.RadioNumber = item.Data.EndpointId.ToString();
                jsonDict.MeterType = item.Data.MarketType.ToString();
                jsonDict.Read = ((Endpoint100G)item.Data).Reading.Read.ToString();
                jsonDict.ModuleType = item.Data.EndpointTypeName;
                jsonDict.ServiceType = item.Data.MarketType.ToString();

                itemsList.Add(jsonDict);
                Console.WriteLine("Count:" + itemsList.Count);
                listView.ItemsSource = itemsList;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void EventStopped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("STOPPED");
        }

        private async void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void ListView_Refreshing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnRefreshDevicesList();
        }

        private void OnRefreshDevicesList()
        {
            
            listView.EndRefresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `itemsList` should be an `ObservableCollection<T>`, not a `List<T>`

Comment: and do not reassign `ItemsSource`

Comment: Thanks @Jason that did it, so simple yet i couldnt see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to @Jason from this

```
private List<JsonDict> itemsList = new List<JsonDict>();
```

To this

```
private ObservableCollection<JsonDict> itemsList = new ObservableCollection<JsonDict>();
```

Comment: Consider marking it as answer cause it's helpful to others.